# Jquery form validation with a telephone not required but only 11 characters

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I build this form, and this is the job below. I was wondering if you can help me to see if what I've done is correct.

The ‘More Information’ form should include client-side validation.
The creative identifies what fields in the form are required, but there are also some additional levels of validation that should be implemented. The complete set of requirements regarding validation is as follows:

- The field ‘Contact name’ is required and needs to be populated to allow submission
- The field ‘Contact email address’ is required and needs to be populated to allow submission
- The field ‘Contact email address’ needs to conform to the format of an email address to allow submission.
- The field ‘Contact phone number’ is NOT required, although, if this field is populated, it must contain only digits and be a maximum of 11 characters long upon submission.

EG:
http://jsfiddle.net/bhdry/52/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with this. It all appears to be working fine for me. The validation is exactly as you say it should be.

The phone number is fine because of the masked input. This makes sure it is only in the format you specify so that means when you send it to the server it will either be blank or the format you specified.

Of course, you will need to do additional server side validation.

Comment: what do you mean for server side validation? have you got an eg?

Comment: Well, when you send this data (name, email, etc) to the server, you will need to validate it again on the server. How are you sending this data to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It works as you think it should work, only digits are allowed and if user enters less than 11 digits, the contents is not preserved. [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhdry/52/)

Comment: so, is it what has been asked ?

Comment: yes it is!. It is completely fulfilling all of above mentioned requirements.